# Ionic blank screen issue for ios device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In ionic app for ios devices, when I used application, then if I tap outside the screen then screen goes blank. It will show white screen. But this issue only occurs in iPhone devices, not on Android ones.

I have also tried replacing `<ion-content>` with `<ion-scroll>`.. and also set `overflow-scroll="false"`

And also put this in index.html file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

But I am still getting same issue.

Could anyone help me out with this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Outside the screen means?

Answer (score 1):

i Had the same problem... In my case it worked iOS and Android

I configure my config.xml like that and working i think that can help you

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Comment: This is not working for me, but Its create another issue. i.e. Splash screen stop moving(not getting next screen) after adding all those lines. swipeBackEnabled to false in app.js works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue in one of mine ionic application. I just did **swipeBackEnabled** to **false** in **app.js** and magic works for me.

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
```